# Regex with Swift

Tags: ios, regex, swift

How can I remove paragraph tags that are wrapped around youtube links from my string? They look like this:

```
<p>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2U_41PxnXhA</p>
```

I still want `<p>` tags around normal text, just not when there's youtube links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using NSRegularExpression

```
var contentText = "<p>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2U_41PxnXhA</p>"
let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern:"<p>(.*?)</p>", options:nil, error:nil)!
let match = regex .matchesInString(contentText, options:nil, range: NSRange(location:0, length:contentText.length))

for r in match
{
   var url = contentText.substringWithRange(r.rangeAtIndex(1))
}
```

good luck!

Comment: Wont this get rid of all paragraph tags?

Comment: Getting error on rangeAtIndex: NSRange is not convertible to Range<String.Index>

Comment: Use `var url = (contentText as NSString).substringWithRange(r.rangeAtIndex(1))`

Comment: chagne the contentText string type, 
`var contentText:NSString = "<p>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2U_41PxnXhA</p>"`

Comment: lol - dbl post. One more thing: use `NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive` instead of the nil option since the HTML tags might also be capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

Regex:

```
<p>(https?://www\.youtube\.com\b.*?)<\/p>
```

In ios, i think you need to escape the `\` one more time,

```
"<p>(https?://www\\.youtube\\.com\\b.*?)</p>"
```

Then replace the matched characters by,

```
$1
```

or  `\1`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rX5eE5/7)